# ggplot: order data frame or axis so that characters are before numbers

Tags: r, heatmap, yaxis

I have data structured as per this example, and would like to create a heatmap from it. I have problems structuring the y axis so that the character "A" is at the top, and the numbers below it are in ascending order.

For the presented example I would like to have A, 1, 2 and A, 3, 4. Using `fct_relevel` and `fct_rev`, I found ways to have either the "A" in the correct place, or the axis in the order that I want it, but I can't figure out a solution for both without messing up my facets.

Thanks for any help!

[image: current Plot]

Example Data:

```
frws <- rep(c('AtTop', 'Bottom'), each=12)
fcols <- rep(c('left', 'right', 'left', 'right'), each=6)
xlabs <- rep(c('a', 'b'), times=12)
mdat <- data.frame(frws, fcols, xlabs, ID)
mdat$ID <- rep (c('A', '1', '2','A', '1', '2','A' ,'3', '4','A' ,'3', '4'), each=2)
mdat$numbers <- c(1,1,2,3,3,1,1,1,1,3,1,2,1,1,2,3,2,3,1,1,0,2,0,3)
```

No success here:

```
mdat <- within(mdat, ID <- ordered(ID, levels = (unique(ID))))
mdat <- mdat %>% 
  mutate(ID = fct_relevel(ID, "A"))
```

The plot I would like to have with ordered y axis:

```
mdat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(xlabs, ID)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = numbers), colour = "white") +
  facet_rep_grid(frws ~ fcols, scale="free")+
  scale_fill_gradientn( colors = c("white", "green",  "red"), 
                        values = rescale (c(0,1.0,2.5)))
```

Comment: Isn't that just a matter of setting ID as a factor with the desired order of the levels? E.g. `mdat$ID <- factor(mdat$ID, rev(unique(mdat$ID)))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

library(tidyverse)

```
#Data
frws <- rep(c('AtTop', 'Bottom'), each=12)
fcols <- rep(c('left', 'right', 'left', 'right'), each=6)
xlabs <- rep(c('a', 'b'), times=12)
mdat <- data.frame(frws, fcols, xlabs)
mdat$ID <- rep (c('A', '1', '2','A', '1', '2','A' ,'3', '4','A' ,'3', '4'), each=2)
mdat$numbers <- c(1,1,2,3,3,1,1,1,1,3,1,2,1,1,2,3,2,3,1,1,0,2,0,3)

#Format levels
valev <- unique(mdat$ID)
va1 <- valev[valev=='A']
valev <- valev[valev!='A']
valev <- sort(valev,decreasing = T)
levs <- c(valev,va1)
mdat$ID <- factor(mdat$ID,levels = levs)

#Plot

mdat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(xlabs, ID)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = numbers), colour = "white") +
  facet_rep_grid(frws ~ fcols, scale="free")+
  scale_fill_gradientn( colors = c("white", "green",  "red"), 
                        values = rescale (c(0,1.0,2.5)))
```

Output:

[image]